# Is it possible to change the color of the progressbar when the progress reaches a specific progress in xml

Tags: android, android-progressbar

Is there a way to set the color of a `progressBar` in XML, while the progress is going on?
I want to change the color of my progress at 80% to red.
Is there a way to to this in xml? So I just can copy paste my `progressBar` without coding it manually everytime...

Comment: I don't think it's possible in XML you have to do it programmatically. You can write a common util function that takes a progress bar as an argument and changes its color when it exceeds 80%.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot change the color at runtime using xml.
If you can change your ProgressBar to SeekBar, you can easily listen to the progress change & as it reaches 80, you can change the color.

```
seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
 @Override
 public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
  }

 @Override
 public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
   }

 @Override
 public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

   }
 });
 }
```